# Where does webistrano store custom recipes?

Tags: capistrano, administration, webistrano

I'm trying to figure out where does webistrano keep its custom recipes (I want to copy them), and I can't seem to locate them. I've scoured the installation folder on the server to no avail.

Does anyone know where they are kept?

Answer (score 0):

Recipes created inside the admin interface are stored in the database. The `recipes` table holds the information for the recipe and the revision to be executed on, include the actual code for the current version. The `recipe_versions` holds a complete copy of each version of the recipe.

The project types (templates) are created inside the repository at `lib/webistrano/template/`

Comment: Nope, sorry. (A) I don't see such a folder path. (B) Anywhere there's a templates folder I see only a maintenance.rhtml file.

Comment: Hmm I see them https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/tree/master/lib/webistrano/template

Answer (score 0):

They were stored in its backend database.